# What is static/dynamic power?

Tags: power

I'm learning about power management in OMAP35x and I came across these terms. I can't seem to find a good explanation anywhere. What do they mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static means the power it will always draw no matter what you do, typically this is due to transistor leakage.  Dynamic power will vary, for instance if you run it at full speed vs putting it into sleep mode it will draw more or less power respectively.  As transistors switch on and off they draw more power and dissipate more heat.

Comment: So is total_power = static_power + dynamic_power or total_power = dynamic_power?

Comment: total power = static_power + dynamic

Comment: @EpsilonVector: Total power is static power plus dynamic, though in many cases when a device isn't sleeping the dynamic power will be so much larger than the static power that dynamic power and total power would be essentially synonymous.  For example, if a 3.000V device was specified to use 5uA when sleeping and 10.000mA when running full speed, static power would be 15uW, running power 30.000mW, and dynamic power 29.985mW (i.e. 30.0mW).